# Netsh http command gives me an invalid handle error message

Tags: http, netsh

When running **netsh http delete iplisten ipaddress=0.0.0.0** i get the error message displayed below.

*IP address delete failed, error: 6
The handle is invalid*

Anyone have an idea as to why?

Answer (score 0):

Delete all the entries in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters\SslBindingInfo
That resolved the "The handle is invalid" error for me.

-Ameen

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, also had System PID 4 listening on port 80 problem

I had these 2 items under but didn't remove them

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters\SslBindingInfo\0.0.0.0:443

Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters\SslBindingInfo\0.0.0.0:8172
```

I DID removed these from `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters\UrlAclInfo`

```
http://*:80/
http://*:443/
```

`netsh http show` COMMANDS doesn't give me invalid handle now and IIS port 80 works again.